# REGEXP_EXTRACT specific string in Google Data Studio

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I have an ID in the `session_id` column that is currently formatted as:

```
[P0000000000109669288] (https://link.com/#/company::_e73d4f95_a66f_4366_b32a_3c14be37d510?p=i_start:2019-09-17%2000:45:00&p=i_timezone:America/Los_Angeles&f=session_id:eq:P0000000000109669288)
```

I need to get just the `P0000000000109669288`, so the data between the brackets, and have these displayed in a new column in a table in Google Data Studio. The end goal is to create a joint table with this ID as joint key (in the other data source the ID is also showing without the link).

I tried some `REGEXP_EXTRACT` formulas, but can't seem to get it to work:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(session_id, "[(.*?)]")
```

Comment: `[]` create a character class and all characters inside it are the allowed characters. You likely need to escape those characters. Otherwise your `().*?` are all literal characters and have no special regex context. Maybe `\[([^\]]+)\]` would work for you

Answer (score 0):

With a combination of the answers above I think I found it:

SUBSTR(session_id, 2, 40).

This extracts everything starting from the second symbol in the string, and stops at the 40th symbol of the string. Since all ID's have the same length, this was the fix!!

Thank you so much all! Now I still have some issues with joining the tables but I will create another thread if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487) formula does the trick:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(session_id, "^\\[(.*)\\]")
```

***RegEx Breakdown***:
When *session_id* starts `^` with `[` capture all `(.*)` characters between `[` and `]`. NOTE: Calculated fields in Google Data Studio use the two backslashes `\\` for special RegEx characters and the escape sequence, thus the use of `\\[` and `\\]`.

To restrict the capture to `A-Z0-9`, this does the trick:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(session_id, "^\\[([A-Z0-9]+)\\]")
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/288f5c42-7d54-4b26-9c19-177a88c80faa) (Google Sheets Embedded) to demonstrate.

[image: 2]]